# Problems posing a kitbash cable run along a path/bezier curve using curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, transforms, geometry

I've attached my blend file below

https://we.tl/t-2aNH8RbZKT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the rotation of your object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), put it at the same location as the curve's location (select the curve, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then select the object and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*). Select your object and in *Edit* mode rotate it so that it aligns with the X axis:

[image]

In the modifier choose *Deform Axis > -X*. Now it should work if you move it in *Object* mode:

[image]

Comment: thankk uu!!! rly appreciate your help here